# How to share the Google Checkout interface for one app only?

Tags: android, google-checkout

I have developed an app for a contract, and as per the contract I should be the publisher of the app and give a percentage of the revenue to my associate.

Hence, I would like to provide access to my associate to the purchase orders. However, I have developped other paid apps for myself, and I would appreciate that my associate could only see purchases for the app we developed together.

I shared the Checkout account with read priviledges only, however all the orders are visible.

Would it be possible to share only a portion of the app purchases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you cannot restrict access to only a subset of the orders.

I think your best option is to create another separate account for your paid apps. This will take care of the restricted access issue as well as make it easier to figure out the total revenue per app.

Comment: It'd be the best solution if it was my only customer. I thought about: making him trust me without access, give him full access, publish with another account. First one is highly unlikely, I don't like the second one, and I don't think it is a good idea to create a new account for every customer. I guess that for my next customers I'll put in the contract that they have to publish the app by themselves and provide _me_ an access to their checkout account.